# R doesn't recognize the Arabic language

Tags: r, utf-8, text-mining

I am working with data in the Arabic language in R, so I set the local Arabic as shown here
`Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE","arabic")`.

then I opened the data and assigned it to a variable and I can read it so clear, but when I dealt with it the result on the console bar becomes symbols can't understand it like this

`ظ…ط¨ط§ظ„ط؛ ظپظٹظ‡ط§`.

it is my first time faced this problem any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think "arabic" is not a correct locale, so you cannot set it as `LC_CYPE`.

The normal format is: `en_US.UTF-8`, so language, country/territory, and now pretty standard the suffix `.UTF-8` or `UTF8` to specify the encoding.

You should use `locale -a` on terminal to find the locale available on your computer. Read the documentation of your operating system, on how to add new locales (and on https://superuser.com/ for Windows, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ for Unix and Linux (Ubuntu has also own stack exchange site) or https://apple.stackexchange.com/ for MacOs.

But I think you are misinterpreting the locale. The locale is on how the system should interact with you. It is not about the data you are using. But for sorting (R uses locale), and display.